# How Do I Unlock the 'ilomilo shuffle'?

Tags: ilomilo

On the story selection screen of [ilomilo](http://www.gamespot.com/xbox360/puzzle/ilomilo/index.html?tag=result;title;0), I have the option of playing *first adventure*, or *ilomilo shuffle*, which is locked.  How do I unlock it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spoiler!

> You can find the Shuffle game in Chapter 3's "Wet Ink" level. There is also a cheat code to unlock it: Just press LT, RT, LB, RB in the main menu. (Apparently Shuffle will not actually appear unlocked in the menu if you use the cheat, but you still can play it).

<sub>Source: [[1]](http://game.downloadatoz.com/tutorial,8266,how-to-unlock-ilomilo-shuffle.html)</sub>